# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in magento 1.9 configurable product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have installed SCP plugin for configurable products in magento 1.9. Everything is working fine but images are not getting changed when particular product is selected and it is showing this error on line 240 of product view page:
}Product.Options = Class.create();

I dont know whats wrong with it. Please help me out.

Comment: can you share url?

Comment: I can't share it on public portal

Comment: This is the first error:    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier and when i got to the file it shows error on view page line which i have already mentioned. And second error is the following:::::::::: Uncaught TypeError: Product.ConfigurableSwatches is not a constructor
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (250-tc-sheets-config.html:140)
    at HTMLDocument.responder (prototype.js:5575)
    at fire (prototype.js:5734)
    at HTMLDocument._methodized [as fire] (prototype.js:438)
    at HTMLDocument.fireContentLoadedEvent (prototype.js:5820)

Answer (score 0):

You can change in the following files :-

1) app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/view/type/configurable/swatch-js.phtml

2) Change this section in above file :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
        var swatchesConfig = new Product.ConfigurableSwatches(spConfig);
    });
</script>
```

To this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
        if (Product.ConfigurableSwatches) {
            var swatchesConfig = new Product.ConfigurableSwatches(spConfig);
        }
    });
</script>
```